# Delete last 2 characters wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

im having trouble with getting actual value of woocommerce cart to the value of input. Always im getting the value with the currency symbol at the end of the string, so the result looks like "11.50 $" and I need to get numeric only result like "11.50". This is how my code looks like.

```
<input id ="in-cart" type="text" value="<?php

$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();

$cart_sum = substr( $cart, 0, - 2); //// doesnt work

echo wp_strip_all_tags($cart); ?>"
```

I would like to ask, if there is any possibility to cut last 2 characters of $cart string.

Ive tried to add

```
$cart_sum = substr( $cart, 0, - 2);
```

and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `get_cart_total()` will return the cart total as HTML content. You need to strip the HTML tags and entities to get the value. The below code will do that irrespective of the currency position chosen in currency option in settings.

```
<input id ="in-cart" type="text" value="<?php

$cart = strip_tags(WC()->cart->get_cart_total());
$cart = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$cart);
echo wp_strip_all_tags($cart);?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Function :

```
mb_substr($string, 0, -2);
```